# Are there advantages to disable Touch drive?

Tags: asphalt-9-legends

In the new game Asphalt 9 there is an option to enable or disable Touch Drive. What the option basically does is steer for you. Turning it off gives you more control oveer the steering oveer the car. But frrom what I have experienced so far, is that the auto-steering is working quite nice, and I don't miss any items/corners. So why do I want to turn it off anyway? Are there any advantages turning it off?

Comment: If a racing game is steering for you, are you even playing it?

Comment: it's more fun imo, and you get bragging rights.  Also, I imagine it will allow you to excel more and pull off some really good stunts if that interests you.  More control equals more possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to making a jump in the hunted mode, the Auto Driver misses the ramps and crashes into the police barricade.

Comment: I always have enough time to decide. Time moves even slower at those points it seems, so this has not been an issue. I never missed one with touch drive.

Answer (score 1):

Touch Drive can be useful in many ways, including:

- Allows you to go around corners faster
- Gaining more control over the vehicle

The only downside is that it might be difficult to work with. Therefore it is suggested for you to turn it off and drive all by yourself.